# Как вернуть слова в исходный текст?

Tags: php

Я создал json , в котором все русских слова превратились в символы:

> u0433u043eu0434-1

Я этот json вывожу так:

```
$words = json_decode($my_json, true);
foreach ($data as $k=> $word) {
    echo $word;
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

В итоге получаю такой вывод:

```
u0410-1
u0433u043eu0434-1
u04101
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: покажите теперь, как вы его создали

Comment: Попробуйте во $flags добавить JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Comment: @teran очень просто. ‘$data = [‘слово1’,’слово2’]’. $data = json_encode($data); и полученный $data я записал в MySQL в столбец с типом json